# "No module named bs4"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to use beautiful soup in VSCode on Windows 10; I was told to import beautiful soup with the line "from bs4 import Beautiful Soup" but I keep getting the error message that the module cannot be found. I definitely downloaded beautifulsoup, is there a specific place I am supposed to unzip the files?

I tried moving the files I unzipped from the beautifulsoup zip drive into the same folder as the programs I am working on, but to no avail. I expected the warning message to go away if I did this but it is still there.

Thank you

P.S. this is my first time posting a question on here; I see people ask for OS so I said I am using windows 10 and VSCode, what other info is generally required/wanted?

Comment: " I definitely downloaded beautifulsoup" - Have you read [the installation part of the documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup)?

Comment: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` is what you need to do. (ie. remove the space).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure u have BeautifulSoup installed, run `pip install beautifulsoup4`

Change `from bs4 import Beautiful Soup` to `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have pip installed along with python, all you need to do is run `pip install beautifulsoup4` or `python3 -m pip install beautifulsoup4` in a command prompt window. Using pip is the recommended way to install and use python modules, and it is the easiest and fastest method.

> I was told to import beautiful soup with the line "from bs4 import Beautiful Soup"

Also make sure you are importing `BeautifulSoup` from bs4 (no space), otherwise an error will be thrown.

Alternatively, you can follow the instructions [on this webpage](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup) about installing bs4 using the tarball. Let me know if you have any problems with this.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you've chosen the correct python interpreter.

You can use shortcuts **Ctrl+Shift+P** and type `Python: Select Interpreter`  to choose the python interpreter which you installed the package in.